# My code results in parse error because of my use of guards

Tags: haskell, syntax, pattern-guards

I have the following code:

```hs
parseExpr :: [String] -> (Ast,[String])
parseExpr [] = error "Incorrect"
parseExpr (s:ss) | all isDigit s = (Tall (read s),ss)
              | s == "-" = let (e,ss') = parseExpr ss in (Min e,ss')
              | s == "+" = (Sum e e',ss'') where
                           (e,ss') = parseExpr ss
                           (e',ss'') = parseExpr ss'
              | s == "*" = (Mult e e',ss'') where
                           (e,ss') = parseExpr ss
                           (e',ss'') = parseExpr ss'
```

When I try to run it, I get an error saying "parse error on input '|'. The line it's talking about is this one:

```hs
...
                           (e',ss'') = parseExpr ss'
->            | s == "*" = (Mult e e',ss'') where
                           (e,ss') = parseExpr ss
...
```

I think I understand why. I would think it's because I have two lines above that are not shielded by guards, and that haskell then get's confused when there suddenly appears another guard below. But how can I then add additional guards after these cases?

I've tried using semicolons to separate new lines, but I'm very new with Haskell and therefore don't know much about its syntax.

Comment: Use one where for all guards

Comment: I think Thomas is right. The parse error probably happens because after parsing the first `where` the code will think your function is over.

Comment: Even ignoring the parse error, using a single `where` in this instance will cut down on a fair amount of duplicate code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to use braces *(although of course you could)*. But you do need to be careful with indentation. It is not as hard as it may at first seem.

That being said, it is true that you cannot use `where` inside a guarded expression. You have to use `let` in such case, like this:

```
parseExpr :: [String] -> (Ast,[String])
parseExpr [] = error "Incorrect"
parseExpr (s:ss) | all isDigit s = (Tall (read s),ss)
              | s == "-" = let (e,ss') = parseExpr ss in (Min e,ss')
              | s == "+" = let (e,ss') = parseExpr ss
                               (e',ss'') = parseExpr ss'
                           in (Sum e e',ss'')
              | s == "*" = let (e,ss') = parseExpr ss
                               (e',ss'') = parseExpr ss'
                           in (Mult e e',ss'')
```

However, in your case here, the guard expressions are so simple they can be replaced with pattern matches. *(And it is advisable to use the opportunity. Pattern matching is your best friend in Haskell.)* In that case you use `where`.

```
parseExpr :: [String] -> (Ast,[String])
parseExpr [] = error "Incorrect"
parseExpr (s:ss) | all isDigit s = (Tall (read s),ss)
parseExpr ("-":ss) = (Min e,ss') where (e,ss') = parseExpr ss
parseExpr ("+":ss) = (Sum  e e',ss'') where (e, ss' ) = parseExpr ss
                                            (e',ss'') = parseExpr ss'

parseExpr ("*":ss) = (Mult e e',ss'') where (e, ss' ) = parseExpr ss
                                            (e',ss'') = parseExpr ss'
```

Comment: Thank you! I can see now that I need to learn more about pattern matching. Excellent answer.